# Can the OS be the problem that makes my pc not show correctly?

Tags: 14.04, updates, gui

Let me explain what I mean by showing incorrectly: http://m.imgur.com/xfaRNnE
I run Ubuntu 14.04, I updated the software througj the automatic updater and after restarting this happened. It is impossible for me to navigate through GUIs or use the screen at all. It is not a hardware problem, checked by connecting pc to other screens and they all had the same problem. Is there any solution besides reinstalling the OS to fix this?

Comment: please mention your video card?

Answer (score 0):

It is a video card problem. You should reinstall the video driver, or even better: save your `/home` directory and reinstall the complete system from scatch. It will be faster than trying to debug this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have proprietary drivers installed for your video card, press CTRL-ALT-F1 to go to a console, remove them with apt. If you don't, maybe you can try to install the latest or previous stable proprietary video card driver.